# Query slow after adding additional where clause a.accountActivity IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have one table 'AccountActivity' and this contains many nullable columns.
I construct the query for this table:

```
SELECT * FROM AccountActivity WHERE accountActivityDate IS NOT NULL
```

while execute the query it will take more time.

Comment: Do you have index created on accountActivityDate ?

Comment: hi balaji .. yes i have created the index on accountActivityDate column

Comment: Hi Any one help me .. while execute the query ,why it will take more time for excution.